# Selenium WebDriver: Size of the text field

Tags: selenium, webdriver, textfield, gettext, capacity

I'm stuck with one basic issue in Selenium WebDriver: How to test a capacity of the text field in the form? I have used **.sendKeys(String)** and then I tried to get the text back with **.getText()**, but it doesn't work. It retrieves an empty String. 
How to test the size of text field then? How to compare my input and actual data? 
This is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.Assert;
public class main {
public static void main(String [] args){
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("http://energy-telecom.org/ServiceReview/quote.php");
String valid="0123456789";
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("firstName"));
element.sendKeys(valid);
System.out.println("input: "+element.getText());
//Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), valid, "Valid_TEXT");
}
```

} 
My output:

```
input:
```

I know that I can use **.getAttributes**, but I'm curious can I retrieve this value.
Obviously, the last line is commented because it gives an exception.
Thank you.
PS: Don't submit anything in this form pls :D

Comment: What is `Valid_TEXT` in your code? Did you assign anything to this variable? Also please paste the exception your are getting which will be helpful for debugging

Comment: Sure, I forgot to post an output; I updated my question

Comment: @GeorgeRevkov: You shouldn't use `getText()` for input fields, use `getAttributes()`, because the text you see is the value. What do you mean by "but I'm curious is it real to get back something that you put in this field"?

Comment: @GeorgeRevkov: Then use `getAttributes()`. You are talking about how many characters in the textbox or the actual size(length/width) of it?

Comment: I mean: is it real to retrieve this input? Thanks, it works if to use getAttribute("value").

Comment: @GeorgeRevkov: What do you mean `is it REAL`?

Comment: Are there any ways to retrieve this value :D Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For input, the text is the value, so you may try

```
System.out.println("input: "+ element.getAttribute("value"));
```